# Changed cache cookies in 36, can't login now (magento)

Tags: magento

Just made a noob mistake. Changed cache cookies in admin and now can't login, because cookies time is too short, I think.

Do any know where I could in code or somewhere change cache cookies time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All settings in System > Configuration are saved in `core_config_data` table. You will need to edit the specific entries by xpath ("path" column). The xpath for what you are reporting is `admin/security/session_cookie_lifetime`. Ref http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml

Comment: After changing it, manually flush cache by deleting all mage--? subfolders in var/cache. This will flush cached config information and force a re-read from the database.

Comment: Any time I've had login issues in the past, clearing /var/session/ has helped.

Comment: Upon the keyboard of the server where your site runs... Wonder if it's still as effective when a KVM switch or remote desktop is being used.